# Why am I getting the error "<%= %> cannot be connected with equals()"

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am getting the error

> <%= %> cannot be connected with equals().

I am making a JSP and Servlet app.

I put the following in my JSP file:

```css
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><%= item.getName() %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <% if(request.getAttribute("code").equals.new(<%= item.getCode() %>)){
                 %>
                 <input type="submit" value="Click"
                 onclick="JavaScript:Submit(<%= item.getCode() %>,<%= item.getCount() %>);"
                 <%
                     if(request.getAttribute("count") != null){
                         if(request.getAttribute("count").equals("0")){
                             %>
                             disabled
                             <%
                         }
                     }
                 %>
```

`<% if(request.getAttribute("code").equals.new(<%= item.getCode() %>))`
has too many errors, so the grammar is wrong, but I do not know how to fix it. Could someone tell me how to connect equals() and <%= %>?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to embed a JSP tag within another JSP tag. Remove the JSP tags from around `item.getCode()`.

```
<% if(request.getAttribute("code").equals.new(item.getCode())){
%>
```

Comment: or better yet use JSTL